# How can I allow the most recently raised event to cancel prior events?

Tags: c#, events

My event will be fired whenever a specific file on my system is modified. The processing done on the file when the event is fired is estimated to be around 10 minutes.  I'd like to know if it's possible to cancel the processing and restart the processing if the file is modified again before the processing for the first modification is done. If so, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Not sure why this was closed... I had already accepted an answer so I don't see how this is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, etc. when someone can clearly understand what it is I am trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me you don't want to cancel the event but the handling of the previous event. Assuming that's the case, you'll need to make your file-processing code cancellation aware.

I suggest you use a [CancellationToken and CancellationTokenSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx) because they are available in the framework already. When you start handling the event you create a new cancellation token source and save it somewhere, and clear it when you're done. If you get a new event check whether there's a saved cts, and request a cancellation if that's the case.

The link I included contains some code samples on how to write your processing code.

Comment: This looks like what I'm searching for! Based on the examples provided, it seems that I am forced to place checkpoints along the way to check for the cancellation request, is that correct? Also, after the cancellation is set, how can I start the new process? It seems like I would be using the same CancellationToken, which is already flagged to cancel. Perhaps a Queue of CancellationTokens that are dequeued after the cancel flag is set?

Comment: That is correct. You need to be involved in safely cancelling the operation. Using the TPL you'd get some of that cancellation checks done for you at task boundaries.

Comment: About the second question, you'd just cancel the current CTS, if any, and create a new one to replace the previous one.

Comment: If I were to create a new CT, I'd still need a way to access the CT of the previous event. What would be the best way to manage this?

Comment: You can save the current CTS in a field in the type handling the event. You'd probably want to use Interlocked.Exchange (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337971.aspx) to peform the exchange in a thread-safe manner. Or you could use a lock.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in control of the processing code, you can keep a "current operation" instance that will be checked by the processing code periodically. If the processing is done, set this reference to null.

When a new event is raised, check if the current processing object reference is null. If it is, you can set a boolean flag to true. The processing code sees that at it's next periodic check and stops.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? How does this allow me to cancel the processing that the previously raised event is performing?